# 4K 60Hz refresh rate only works intermittently in Wayland and X11

Tags: graphics, xorg, hdmi, monitor, wayland

I can get a 4K 60Hz refresh rate to work on an Ubuntu Wayland session. I do have a monitor, graphics card, and HDMI cable that all support 4K 60Hz refresh rates (they all work fine in Windows).

At first everything works fine on my system, but eventually videos start playing at double speed, and the voice on all videos is very high pitched. Changing the refresh rate to 30Hz fixes the issue, but I don't want my monitor at 30Hz!

If I logout and log on to X11 I can change the refresh rate to 60Hz and everything works fine... until I reboot or suspend/wake, at which point X11 forces the refresh rate to 30Hz and I lose the option to manually put the refresh back to 60Hz (it disappears, and won't reappear unless I logon to Wayland, logout, then log back into X11).

The best answer I've found to these issues online boils down to "use a displayport port instead of HDMI". Is that really the only answer? Luckily, I have a displayport on my graphics card, and I can buy an adapter to convert to HDMI.